# Spring-Hibernate logging - separate log files

Tags: hibernate, log4j

I am using Spring & Hibernate in my application and I want to set up two different log files - one main log file all the non-sql logging and another file for writing sql queries. This is my log4j.properties file.. But while the sql log file is working as expected..the issue is that the main log file also contains sql queries.. What changes should I make here to to stop writing sql queries to main log file..

```
#application log properties
log4j.appender.rollingFile = org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.rollingFile.File = C:\\myapp\\logs\\app.log
log4j.appender.rollingFile.Threshold = TRACE
log4j.appender.rollingFile.DatePattern = '.'yyyy-MM-dd
log4j.appender.rollingFile.layout = org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout 
log4j.appender.rollingFile.layout.ConversionPattern=%d %5p [%C:%M:%L] - %m%n
log4j.rootLogger = ERROR, rollingFile

#hibernate properties
log4j.appender.file = org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender 
log4j.appender.file.File = C:\\myapp\\logs\\sql.log
log4j.appender.file.Threshold = TRACE
log4j.appender.file.DatePattern = '.'yyyy-MM-dd
log4j.appender.file.layout = org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout 
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d %5p [%C:%M:%L] - %m%n
log4j.logger.jdbc.sqltiming = DEBUG, file
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the additivity behaviour of the appenders in log4j .

> Each enabled logging request for a given logger will be
>   forwarded to all the appenders in that logger as well as the appenders
>   higher in the hierarchy.

Just set the additivity for the logger `jdbc.sqltiming` to false and its log messages will not be propagated to its parent loggers' appenders (i.e. app.log)

```
log4j.additivity.jdbc.sqltiming = false
```

---

**References:**

[See the section `Appenders and Layouts` for more information about Appender Additivity](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/manual.html)

Comment: thanks Nathan and ken.. also with my current configuration log file doesn't have date attached to it until the day is rolled over.. I mean today's logs are written to "app.log" until midnight then I will have "app.log.2011-08-12" - which is actually expected beahavior according to log4j documentation.. but is there a way to change this behavior so that the logs are writtent to current date? I mean I should be able to see "app.log.2011-08-12" today before midnight.. I think by using log4j-extra we can do that but I don't like XML configurations and don't want to go there.. thanks in advance

Comment: @rrkwells , You may try to use `DatedFileAppender` .Contrary to `DailyRollingFileAppender` shipping with log4j, log file names generated by DatedFileAppender always contain today's date. http://logging.apache.org/catalog.html