# logging hibernate events in a separate file than stdout console appender

Tags: java, hibernate, logging, log4j

I want to do something similar to what is described here:
[Spring-Hibernate logging - separate log files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7044892/spring-hibernate-logging-separate-log-files)

to have all logs into the console and the hibernate logs into a file.

show_sql is true for hibernate.
What it does, it is logging the entire output to the console and in the file it logs all output except hibernate output.

log4j.properties look like this currently:

```
log4j.rootLogger=WARN, stdout, hibernate

log4j.appender.stdout = org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout = System.out
log4j.appender.stdout.layout = org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
...
log4j.additivity.stdout = false

log4j.logger.org.hibernate= ALL, hibernate

log4j.appender.org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.hibernate.File= <path to file>
log4j.appender.org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
...

log4j.logger.hibernate.sqltiming = DEBUG, hibernate
log4j.additivity.jdbc.sqltiming = false
log4j.additivity.hibernate = false
```

I tried a log of things, including additivity options, but the hibernate output refuses to go to the file and remains in the console. I would appreciate if ýou can help me achieve this. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the reason - setting show_sql to true ignores logging configurations and logs into console. I am searching now for options to set logging in the code and having show_sql to false.